# C# how to restart the console application

Tags: c#, arrays, console

I am a begginer, and Im trying to make a Tic-Tac-Toe console game.But when O player has won, it shows, only when X player has made a decision.So that, there can be a situation when 2 players have won.I tried to use if statement to stop aplication but it doesn't help. I think I don't need to restart the application, just start Main again. But how??

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string Player1;
        string Player2;
        int turnPlayer1;
        int turnPlayer2;
        while (CheckTheWinner() == false)
        {
            BoardPlay();
            Console.Clear();
                BoardPlay();
            for ( turnPlayer1 = 0; turnPlayer1 < 1; turnPlayer1++)
            {
                Console.Write("Player O: Choose your field:");
                Player1 = Console.ReadLine();
                Player1Choice(Player1);
            }
            CheckTheWinner();
            Console.Clear();
            BoardPlay();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Player X: Choose your field:");
                Player2 = Console.ReadLine();
                Player2choice(Player2);
            }
            CheckTheWinner();
            Console.Clear();
            BoardPlay();
        }
    }



    public static void Player1Choice(string P1)
    {
        string o = "O";
        for (int i = 0; i < position.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
            {
                if (position[i, j] == P1)
                {
                    position[i, j] = o;  
                }
            }
        };
    }



    public static void Player2choice(string P2)
    {
        string x = "X";
        for (int i = 0; i < position.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
            {
                if (position[i, j] == P2)
                {
                    position[i, j] = x;
                }

            }
        };
    }

    static bool CheckTheWinner()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if (position[i, 0] == position[i, 1] && position[i, 1] == position[i, 2])
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (position[0, i] == position[1, i] && position[1, i] == position[2, i])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (position[0, 0] == position[1, 1] && position[1, 1] == position[2, 2])
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (position[0, 2] == position[1, 1] && position[1, 1] == position[2, 0])
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

"Starting a new game" is basically "repeating the operation of having a game".  Use loops to repeat operations.

First, define the loop condition.  For example, a boolean flag indicating to keep playing:

```
var keepPlaying = true;
```

Then loop as long as that flag is true:

```
var keepPlaying = true;
while (keepPlaying)
{
    // all of the logic currently in your Main method
}
```

Then all you need to do is prompt the player if they want another game and update the variable accordingly.  For example:

```
var keepPlaying = true;
while (keepPlaying)
{
    // all of the logic currently in your Main method

    Console.Write("Would you like to play again? (Y/N): ");
    var playerReply = Console.ReadLine();
    if (playerReply == "N")
        keepPlaying = false;
}
```

You could perhaps simplify the logic a bit, this is mainly for demonstration.  You can also add some logic to check the input, you can add a closing message if the player chooses to quit, add other options, etc.

But the point is that if you want to repeat the game, it's not a matter of restarting the application or re-invoking the `Main` method, it's just a matter of encapsulating what you want to repeat in a loop.

Comment: But how to stop it when someone get 3 in a row? Because, while loop makes whole logic and only after checks the condition. And we can get a situation where there would be 2 winners.I need to stop the game if there is a winner. P.S sorry for bad coding I have been learning for 2 weeks(

Comment: @Folium: Do you mean that the logic of your game itself is broken?  Maybe I misunderstood the question.  If the code you’ve written isn’t working as expected in some way, now is a good time for you to start using a debugger to step through the code and observe its runtime behavior.  When you do that, which specific operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used at the time?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: it works, but I want it to stop, when someone get three in a row, it stops, but after whole while loop has passed, soo there is an apportunity for another player to win. I want: when someone get three in a row, while loop must stop, and start a new game. I

Comment: @Folium: Do you check for a winner after every turn?  It sounds like you allow two turns before checking.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't help, it just stops when while have done the whole logic

Comment: @Folium: What did you try?  What about that specific operation didn’t do what you expect?  Alternatively, consider a different approach.  What if instead of performing two turns per loop, you instead perform one turn per loop and maintain a variable which indicates whose turn it is for any given iteration of the loop?

Comment: I have edited the code, made turns but it didn't help, Idk mb the method of checking the winner is wrong... but after the whole while loop ends, it works...

Comment: @Folium: In your updated code, where you call `CheckTheWinner()` in the middle of the logic, what do you do with the result of that method?  .... Nothing.  If the method returns `true`, shouldn't you `break` from the loop or something?

Comment: @Folium: Additionally... You have a variable you never use called `turnPlayer2`, and your `for` loops only ever loop from `0` to `1`, which means they only ever loop *once*.  So why are they loops in the first place?  Remove anything that's logically unnecessary and you'll probably find your code easier to follow and understand.  A loop that only ever loops *once* doesn't need to be a loop at all.  Just perform the operations you want to perform.

Comment: ohh, ty man, sorry for being stupid, I am begginer in programming,You have helped me so much, ty for wasted time trying to understand and help me)